# I haveto write methods of same functionality again and again for CRUD (Create , Read , Update , Delete) *new in laravel*

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function create() { $Gallery= GalleryModel::all(); return view('admin.gallery',compact('Gallery')); }
```

```
public function video() { $Video= VideoModel::all(); return view('admin.video',compact('Video')); }
```

```
public function team() { $Team = TeamModel::all(); return view('admin.team',compact('Team')); }
```

Is where is any way to make single method for different pages

Answer (score 2):

There are many of ways to do that. The general idea is to use Traits.

```
// ControllerTrait.php
trait ControllerTrait {
    // Here you include all yor controller's methods
}
```

Then, in every controller you use your trait

```
// YourController.php
class YourController extends Controller {
    use ControllerTrait;
    // The rest of your controller's code
}
```

You can even go further if you consider classes inheritance:

You could create a base controller like this:

```
// MyBaseController.php
class BaseController extends Controller {
    use ControllerTrait; // <= you can mix the strategies for more power
     // All your BaseController's methods
}
```

An then let your controllers extend from the base one instead:

```
// YourController.php
class YourController extends BaseController {
    //
}
```

You could, in the end, just edit you BaseController and your ControllerTrait and ease your life a lot.

NOTE: Editted because you werer talking about Controllers and I was thinking about Models, but you can surely use the same principle for managing your models.

NOTE 2: Traits are better for methods that really **will work as default** for all controllers, and keep in the BaseModel those that **will need to be customized** in any of the inheriting controllers. For example:

```
// MyBaseController.php
class BaseController extends Controller {
    protected function a($request) {
        //
    }
}

// YourController.php
class YourController extends BaseController {
    protected function a($request) {
        $request = $modifiedRequest; // You can modify the inputs
        parent::a($request); // <== Execute the parent method;
    }
}
```